# How do I turn off StandardForm formatting for Piecewise, KroneckerDelta and ConditionalExpression?

Tags: front-end, output-formatting, display, boxes

I find the `StandardForm` formatting for `Piecewise`, `KroneckerDelta`, and `ConditionalExpression` to be very annoying.

How do I turn off the formatting for these objects, without changing their `TraditionalForm` formatting?

Comment: In what form do you want them displayed? InputForm? TraditionalForm? Custom form?

Comment: @Bob For example, I am looking for `KroneckerDelta[a,b]` to format as is without using `δ`.

Answer (score 1):

When you define a piecewise function, you may wrap InputForm around the definition to force the output to be in input form.
E.g. f1 will print in standard form and f2 in input form:

```
f1[x_] := 
 Piecewise[{{1, 0 < x <= 1}, {2, 1 < x <= 2}, {3, 2 < x <= 3}}]
f2[x_] := 
 InputForm[
  Piecewise[{{1, 0 < x <= 1}, {2, 1 < x <= 2}, {3, 2 < x <= 3}}]]
f1[t]
f2[t]
```

Comment: If you include `InputForm` as part of the definition you will have some problems. Look at the result for `f2'[t]` you end up with an `InputForm'` factor. As a general rule, wrappers should not be included in definitions.

Comment: Well, that's true. But do you have a better idea?

Comment: If the OP wants all output in a specified form, use `$Post`. It is more involved if only these functions are to have their `StandardForm` changed.

Answer (score 1):

Following up on Bob Hanlon's comment mentioning `$Post` I found `$PrePrint` and its documentation and came up with the following solution:

```
PrePrintFormats=<|
    KroneckerDelta->FullForm,
    Piecewise->FullForm,
    ConditionalExpression->FullForm
|>;
$PrePrint=If[MemberQ[Keys[PrePrintFormats],Head[#]],PrePrintFormats[Head[#]][#],#]&;
```

This outputs `KroneckerDelta`, `Piecewise` and `ConditionalExpression` using their respective `FullForm`. This changes only the `OutputForm` of attached to those symbols without affecting other forms like `TraditionalForm` or `StandartForm`.

[image: Output]

I also tried a more direct approach by unprotecting the Symbols and trying to add UpValues on `Format[...,OutputForm]` but this did not work. I am not sure if this modification to `$PrePrint` has any nasty side-effects but I think the variable is meant for stuff like this so it might be fine.

EDIT: Using `InputForm` for the output formatting in cells with multiple outputs causes some outputs not to be printed (no real idea why). `FullForm` seems to work better. But further testing is required.

Answer (score 1):

After playing around, I figured the easiest way is to simply define the `FormatValues` of these symbols manually:

```
Unprotect[Piecewise, KroneckerDelta, ConditionalExpression];
FormatValues[Piecewise] = 
  FormatValues[Piecewise] /. 
   Verbatim[BoxForm`fmt_] | BoxForm`fmt :> TraditionalForm;
FormatValues[
   KroneckerDelta] = {HoldPattern[
     MakeBoxes[KroneckerDelta[BoxForm`a$__], TraditionalForm] /; 
      BoxForm`sufficientVersionQ[6.1]] :> 
    TemplateBox[{RowBox[
       Riffle[Function[BoxForm`x$, 
          MakeBoxes[BoxForm`x$, TraditionalForm], HoldAllComplete] /@ 
         Unevaluated[{BoxForm`a$}], ","]]}, "KroneckerDeltaSeq"], 
   HoldPattern[
     MakeBoxes[KroneckerDelta[BoxForm`n__], TraditionalForm]] :> 
    SubscriptBox[BoxForm`FuncIntBox["δ", KroneckerDelta], 
     If[Length[Unevaluated[{BoxForm`n}]] == 1, 
      MakeBoxes[BoxForm`n, TraditionalForm], 
      RowBox[BoxForm`AddCommas[
        List @@ Function[{BoxForm`x}, 
           MakeBoxes[BoxForm`x, TraditionalForm], {HoldAllComplete}] /@
       HoldComplete[BoxForm`n]]]]]};
FormatValues[ConditionalExpression] = {};
Protect[Piecewise, KroneckerDelta, ConditionalExpression];
```

I have placed these lines of code in my `init.m` file, so they run when the kernel starts up.  Now I don't have to deal with their fancy `StandardForm` typesetting again.

Comment: This method isn't ideal, because it causes *Mathematica* to generate error messages when it tries to display unrelated things, like `SeriesData` *etc* for the first time.  I am still looking for a canonical answer.

Comment: You can set ``BoxForm`UseTextFormattingQ = True``, it works for `Piecewise`  and `ConditionalExpression`, but not for `KroneckerDelta`.