# How can I prevent iconized output from Mathematica automatically?

Tags: front-end, iconize

Is there an option to tell Mathematica not to use iconized in its output?

I find these so annoying. The design is all wrong to tell you the truth. The default should be the other way around. It should be explicit output, and have the user request or change via preferences to ask for iconized output instead.

Here is an example

```
eq = ArcSin[y] == 1/x
Solve[eq, y]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

So now one has to reach to the mouse click on the icon, then click on the `Uniconuze` in order to see what is hidden:

[image: Mathematica graphics]

I want the above result to automatically show up.

I tried this option, but it didn’t have any effect:

```
BoxForm`$NewHolonomicBoxes = False
```

I looked at preferences and searched for any option related to `iconize`, but I didn't see anything. My setting for

[image]

How can I make Mathematica **not** use iconized for any of its output?

I feel like I am using [Microsoft Word](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microsoft_Word) these days when using Mathematica notebooks with all these bells and whistles in the interface.

I want to see math, not icons.

V 13.2 on Windows 10.

Comment: Related: https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/230088/how-do-i-turn-off-standardform-formatting-for-piecewise-kroneckerdelta-and-cond

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Setting

```
BoxForm`$ConditionalExpressionIconizeThreshold = 0
```

should do the trick.

I figured this out by calling

```
GeneralUtilities`PrintDefinitions[ConditionalExpression]
```

and looking at the `MakeBoxes` up value.  You could also call `FormatValues@ConditionalExpression` to see what kinds of conditions are placed on the formatting.

Answer (score 0):

One can see the full expression by appending `// InputForm` (or setting this using `$PrePrint`).

However, I disagree that the "design is all wrong": in fact I think it is a *huge* improvement and an important feature of the Wolfram Language!

For example, consider the output generated by `NDSolve[{y'[x] == y[x], y[0] == 1}, y, {x, 0, 5}]`. The iconization of the interpolating function is brilliant!

But I do agree that users should be able to *easily* change the default settings to their personal preference.

Perhaps Itai Segeev would like to comment?